Why $\mathcal{L}_{\xi_X}\omega =0$ when the action is symplectic?
Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and $G\times M\to M$ a symplectic action on $M$, i.e., each map $M\to M$ by $q\mapsto f\cdot q$ is a symplecticmorphism. If $\xi_X$ is the infintesimal generator of the action (i.e. $\xi_X$ is the vector field on $M$ defined by $(\xi_X)_q\equiv \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(e^{tX}\cdot q)$), then why $\mathcal{L}_{\xi_X}\omega =0$ ? where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the Lie derivative? The same question about a one-form $\theta$ that is invariant under $G$.

I am confused -- what is $X$ in $\xi_X = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} e^{tX}$? Is the group action smooth?

@User203940 we define for each $X\in \mathfrak{g}$, a vector field $\xi_X :M\to TM$ by $q\mapsto (\xi_X)q =\frac{d}{dt}|{t=0}e^{tX}\cdot q$. Yes, it's smooth. Actually, $G$ is a Lie group actos on $M$ smoothly.

Pretty much by definition, the 1-parameter group of diffeomorphisms $\varphi_{\xi_X}^t:M\to M$ generated by the vector field $\xi_X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is
$$
\varphi_{\xi_X}^t = \Phi_{\exp_G(tX)},
$$
where $\Phi_g:M\to M$ denotes the symplectic action on $M$.
So
$$
(\varphi_{\xi_X}^t)^*\omega = (\Phi_{\exp_G(tX)})^*\omega = \omega,
$$
using the fact that the action is symplectic in the second equality. Taking $\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0}$ on both sides then yields
$$
\mathcal{L}_{\xi_X}\omega = 0
$$
by definition of the Lie derivative.

This should follow from Cartan's magic formula:
$$L_{X}\omega = \iota_{X} d\omega + d \iota_{X}\omega,$$
we know $\omega$ is closed, and you have to argue $\iota_{\xi}\omega$ is an exact 1-form. In fact, it is true that the flow of a vector field $V$ preserves the symplectic form iff $L_{V}\omega = 0$.
